# MSAL + MvvmCross Unknown Exception

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, azure-ad-msal

We are converting this Microsoft sample to use MSAL for authentication: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/xamarin-csharp-propertymanager-sample

We started with this Microsoft Xamarin MSAL sample as a baseline: 
https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet

When we try to integrate the MvvmCross framework with MSAL we always rceive an unknown exception from the MSAL library.  This exception cannot be captured in the debugger.

The only difference in our code from the Microsoft MSAL sample code is we are using the MvvmCross framework and the assignment of the UIParent property.

Microsoft MSAL Sample Code (from https://github.com/microsoftgraph/xamarin-csharp-propertymanager-sample):

[Click here to see the Microsoft MSAL Sample Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uOuk.jpg)

Our code that uses the MvvmCross framework with MSAL:

[Click here to see the code that uses the MvvmCross framework with MSAL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJ3HO.jpg)

How do we use MSAL with the MvvmCross framework?

Comment: What version are you using? If it is a preview version then can you please try the latest in myget? We developed and tested against xamarin directly and I cannot comment on mvvm is using xamarin that may cause issues. One thing I can think of is the xamarin  package version differences in mvvm vs MSAL which may cause issues. For example, MSAL uses 24.x version for custom tabs but mvvm may be using 26.x. You should be able to capture the exception in the logs using the callbacks in MSAL logger class.

Comment: Thanks, Kanishk.

Comment: We are using MSAL 1.1.0-preview.

We will try the latest version.

The logging suggestion you made helped.  We found this error.  I'll let you know if we cannot figure it out.

System.MissingMethodException: Method 'MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.MvxNavigatingObject.ShowViewModel' not found.